# Google Play Games Services - Unlocking several achievements at once

Tags: android, google-play

I'm adding Achievements to a game which is already published and has active users. Since the previous version of the app did not have this feature, it may happen that when an existing users installs this new version, I want to check their past statistics and unblock some achievements right after.

So, maybe as soon as they sign into Google Play, I need to send about 5-10 Achievements. The code is fine, but not all of the achievements are getting registered. Imagine something like:

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, "ach_1");
Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, "ach_2");
Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, "ach_3");
Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, "ach_4");
Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, "ach_5");
```

Only a few of them get recorded by Google Play. I did notice however a few exception in the log files such as:

```
Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/[id]
```

I suspect my requests are being blocked. Is there a way to send a batch Achievement update or any other way to work around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Games.Achievements.unlockImmediate(mGoogleApiClient, "ach_1" ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<UpdateAchievementResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(UpdateAchievementResult res) {
            System.out.println(res.getStatus().getStatusCode());
        }

    });
```

to trace achievements unlock result

[Achievements.UpdateAchievementResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.UpdateAchievementResult.html)